# Download single files from GitHub

Tags: git, github, url, download, version-control

What are some tips on downloading a single file from a GitHub repo?

I don't want the URL for displaying the raw file; in the case of binaries, there's nothing.

http://support.github.com/discussions/feature-requests/41-download-single-file

Is it even possible to use GitHub as a "download server"?

If we decide to switch to Google Code, is the mentioned functionality presented there?

Or is there any free-of-charge hosting and VCS for open-source projects?

Comment: For GitLab, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51993087/6309.

Comment: Here's the simplest command-line answer **for sure**! https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228412/how-to-wget-a-github-file/387912#387912. Use `wget full_url_to_raw_file_on_github`.

Comment: Download file using the new [GIthub Code Preview file download](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-files/navigating-files-with-the-new-code-view) option, here is the demo https://stackoverflow.com/a/75601738/4936904

Answer (score 755, accepted):

Git does not support downloading parts of the repository. You have to download all of it. But you should be able to do this with GitHub.

When you view a file it has a link to the "raw" version. The [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) is constructed like so

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repository/branch/filename
```

By filling in the blanks in the URL, you can use [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) or [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) (with the `-L` option, see below) or whatever to download a single file. Again, you won't get any of the nice version control features used by Git by doing this.

Update: I noticed you mention this doesn't work for binary files. You probably shouldn't use binary files in your Git repository, but GitHub has a download section for each repository that you can use to upload files.  If you need more than one binary, you can use a .zip file.
The URL to download an uploaded file is:

```
https://github.com/downloads/user/repository/filename
```

Note that the URLs given above, from the links on `github.com`, will redirect to `raw.githubusercontent.com`. You should not directly use the URL given by this HTTP 302 redirect because, per [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.3): "Since the redirection might be altered on occasion, the client SHOULD continue to use the Request-URI for future requests."

Comment: You can actually download only parts of a repository (in terms of history) using `--depth`. However, it will break further synchronization with the initial repository (since it effectively re-builds a different history).

Comment: Note for posterity: I just tested it and using raw works fine for binary files.

Comment: tried for a ~10 MB zip file got error: Error: blob is too big

Comment: @ina I've been able to get this to work for slightly smaller than 10 MB compressed binaries. GitHub has made it clear on their [disk quota page](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota) and their [downloads tab deprecated blog post](https://github.com/blog/1302-goodbye-uploads) that they want to version/store binaries as minimally as possible.

Comment: The suggested URL format doesn't work for me. I find that [https://raw.github.com/user/repository/branch/filename](https://raw.github.com/user/repository/branch/filename) works.

Comment: @BrianC.: (At least as of 27 August 2013) the URL format mentioned in the answer (`raw` after the repository name) is now automatically redirected to the format you mention (hostname `raw.github.com`). When in doubt, browse to the file in question on github.com and click on the 'Raw' button.

Comment: if you still want to use curl, follow the redirection using the -L option on the command line: curl -L -O https://github.com/user/repository/raw/branch/filename

Comment: I tried this, but the link opens the file in a new browser window. How can I force download the file?

Comment: **Example:** When you want to download latest `.htaccess` for Drupal 7, go to its _Github.com_ [page](https://github.com/drupal/drupal), copy the link `https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/7.x/.htaccess` and change it to `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drupal/drupal/7.x/.htaccess` (change `domain`, `subdomain` and remove `blob`).

Comment: @jonescb this `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/downloads/al2helal/ThesisWork/master/consecutive7pointUp36.output` **404:file not found**. Actual file is [here](https://github.com/al2helal/ThesisWork/blob/master/consecutive7pointUp36.output)

Comment: http://githubenterprise.xyz.com/raw/user/repo/master/File1 Worked for me.

Comment: I'll add this answer for those who want to do this using postman. 1-go to the Github URL of the file which you wanna download,2-click on raw,3-copy the URL, 4- paste it in postman and make a get request to it, 5- feel free to change the type to text/XML/JSON after making a get request ,6 -click on save the response and save it with your desirable file extension.

Answer (score 837):

1. Go to the file you want to download.
2. Click it to view the contents within the GitHub UI.
3. In the top right, **right click** the `Raw` button.
4. Save as...

Comment: Instead of "Save as", copy the URL. Thats the URL of the file. You can now download it with any tool that use the URL to download: wget, your browser, etc.

Comment: @MattParkins I just tried it and I think it DOES work now for large files (even binary file with the "we can't show files that are this big right now" warning)

Comment: This worked fo a single C# file. Perhaps github should add another button for downloading. Right clicking a button is not very intuitive.

Comment: Perfect for most source code files as they rarely exceed the size threshold.

Comment: Just a reminder. Copy the URL of the raw file, i.e. after clicking the Raw option.

Comment: "Save as" -- that's what I was looking for

Comment: Does not work if you don't have a desktop environment.

Comment: @theerrormagnet It actually does. The "raw" link is probably under the three dots "menu" button. Long press that link and you'll have a "download" option.

Answer (score 60):

You can use the V3 API to get a raw file like this (you'll need an OAuth token):

```
curl -H 'Authorization: token INSERTACCESSTOKENHERE' -H 'Accept: 
application/vnd.github.v3.raw' -O -L 
https://api.github.com/repos/*owner*/*repo*/contents/*path*
```

All of this has to go on one line. The `-O` option saves the file in the current directory. You can use `-o filename` to specify a different filename.

To get the OAuth token, [follow these instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use).

I've written this up as [a gist](https://gist.github.com/madrobby/9476733) as well.

Comment: This one is good, but unfortunately it only supports files up to 1 MiB in size.

Comment: If executing this within a program, be sure User-Agent is set.

Comment: Can you give some examples of the path. If you repo is my-repo and the file you want to get is at x/y/z.txt then the URL would be...  It was hard to figure out that /owner/repo/ should be filled in by me.  Thanks.

Comment: This works fine but there is a drawback. You don't always the latest version of a file.
Try to make a modification to a file, don't wait too much and try to retrieve the file using this method. You will get just the previous version instead.

Answer (score 57):

According to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jwebcat/5122366), you can use wget or cURL:

1. Click the file name in a GitHub repo.
2. Click Raw to display the file
   contents.
3. Copy the URL in your browser.
4. In the command line, run either:

   - `wget --no-check-certificate --content-disposition https://URL-from-step3/`
   - `curl -LJO https://URL-from-step3/`

   One more: 
   in RHEL7.6, run the following:

   - `wget https://URL-from-step3/ --output-document=FILE_NAME`

Answer (score 35):

You can use `curl` this way:

`curl -OL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<username>/<repo-name>/<branch-name>/path/to/file`

`O` means that curl downloads the content
`L` means that curl follows the redirection

Answer (score 21):

This is now possible in GitHub for any file. You need to translate your files for raw.github.com. For example, if your file is in your repository at:

```
https://github.com/<username>/<repo>/some_directory/file.rb
```

Using wget you can grab the raw file from:

```
https://raw.github.com/<username>/<repo>/<branch>/some_directory/file.rb
```

[Rails Composer](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-composer/) is a great example of this.

Comment: Some files are hosted on raw.githubusercontent.com

Comment: and some times it's raw2.github.com just fyi

Answer (score 16):

[GitHub Mate](https://github.com/camsong/chrome-github-mate) makes single file download effortless, just click the icon to download, currently it only work on Chrome.

[image: GitHub Mate Download]

Comment: @jcollum Checked just now, works for me. Can you make sure you are using the latest version? or let me know the error. Glad to help you to make it work.

Comment: I am on the newest version of Chrome, 34.0.1847.116, and this surely does not work. What operating system are you using? Im on OS X Mavericks.

Comment: I tested on Chrome 34 in Windows 7 and OS X Mavericks, both work. quite strange if not work huh? Please aware that folder are not downloadable. Maybe you can try on a different machine.

Comment: ok, that method will only work if you have chrome extension.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-mate/baggcehellihkglakjnmnhpnjmkbmpkf

Comment: From this view, simply right-click and save as the file

Comment: THERE IS NO LINK ON ICON THEN HOW TO DOWNLOAD?

Answer (score 16):

There are a variety of ways to handle this, depending on how large the file is, whether or not you need to download folders in addition to files, and if you plan to do this manually or programmatically.

There are six options summarized below. And for those that prefer a more hands-on explanation, I've put together a YouTube video: [Download Individual Files and Folders from GitHub](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1HRvE_Oa_aM).

Also, I've posted a [similar answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59100287/4500152) for those that need to download single folders/directories from GitHub (as opposed to files).

---

**1. GitHub User Interface**

- There's a download button on most images.
- There's a download button on the repository's homepage. Of course, this downloads the entire repo, after which you would need to unzip the download and then manually drag out the specific files you need.

**2. Browser Context Menu**

- Go to the file on GitHub, right click on the "Raw" button to open the browser's context menu. From there, if you're using Google Chrome, select "Save Link As...". Other browser's will have a similar UI, but the selection description may vary. For example, it will be listed as "Download Linked File" and "Download Linked File As" on Safari.

**3. Third Party Tools**

- There are a variety of browser extensions and web apps that can handle this, with [DownGit](https://minhaskamal.github.io/DownGit/) being one of them. Simply paste in the GitHub URL to the file and press the "Download" button. Note that the link should be the GitHub.com hosted repository view, as opposed to the direct file link. File link example: `https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint/blob/master/lib/parse.js`.

**4. Subversion**

- GitHub does not support git-archive (the git feature that would allow us to download specific files). GitHub does however, support a variety of Subversion features, one of which we can use for this purpose. Subversion is a version control system (an alternative to git). You'll need Subversion installed. Grab the GitHub URL for the file you want to download. You'll need to modify this URL, though. You want the link to the repository, followed by the word "trunk", and ending with the path to the nested file. In other words, using the same file link that I mentioned above, we would replace "blob/master" with "trunk". Finally, open up a terminal, navigate to the directory that you want the content to get downloaded to, type in the following command (replacing the URL with the URL you constructed): `svn export https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint/trunk/lib/parse.js`, and press enter.

**5. cURL**

- You'll need cURL installed. Go to the file on GitHub.com, left click on the "Raw" button to get to the direct file link, copy this URL, open a terminal, navigate to the directory that you want the content to get downloaded to, type in the following command, replacing the filename with whatever you want to name it, and replacing the URL with the one you just copied: `curl -o parse.js https://raw.githubusercontent.com/babel/babel-eslint/master/lib/parse.js`.

**6. GitHub API**

- This is actually what DownGit is using under the hood. Using [GitHub's REST API](https://developer.github.com/v3/), make a GET request to the content endpoint. The endpoint can be constructed as follows: `https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path`. After replacing the placeholders, an example endpoint is: `https://api.github.com/repos/babel/babel-eslint/contents/lib/parse.js`. This gives you JSON data for that file, including a download URL (the same download URL that we used in the cURL example above). This method isn't all that useful for a single file, though (you'd be more likely to use it for downloading a specific folder, as detailed in the answer that I linked to above).

Comment: its my understanding that download buttons do not download the entire repo...i could be wrong. here's an example: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/ if you download the repository, you won't get the examples directory; you have to change branches to do that.

Comment: @albert Good catch. That's actually because they specifically excluded specific folders/files in the .gitattributes file: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/.gitattributes

Comment: In the cURL example, `-o parse.js` can be replaced with `-O` to write the file with the same name as the remote file.

Answer (score 13):

There is a chrome extension called [Enhanced Github](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enhanced-github/anlikcnbgdeidpacdbdljnabclhahhmd/related)

It will add a download button directly to the right of each file.

[image]

Comment: This is better than Github Mate solely because it doesn't ask for "Read all your browsing history" permission! 
Remember to right click on download button > Save link as.

Comment: It is necessary to add token from your GitHub's account.

Comment: this's secure to use?

Comment: @Ariansaputra I've been using it for a long time now, never came across any issues. It should be safe. I don't see why it wouldn't be

Answer (score 13):

In 2021 GitHub added a new feature of opening visual studio code right on the web. You can launch it by just pressing full stop aka period key `.`, when you are in any repository.

So for downloading any specific file you can launch the vscode by pressing `.` key then it will display all files of the repository in vscode there you can download any file you want by `right click` > `dowload`.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

To follow up with what thomasfuchs said but instead for GitHub Enterprise users here's what you can use.

`curl -H 'Authorization: token INSERTACCESSTOKENHERE' -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw' -O -L https://your_domain/api/v3/repos/owner/repo/contents/path`

Also here's the API documentation https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents

Comment: Can you give some examples of the path.  If you repo is my-repo and the file you want to get is at x/y/z.txt then the URL would be...  Thanks

Comment: @Gray `https://your_domain/api/v3/repos/{owner}/my-repo/contents/x/y/z.txt`

Comment: if I want to download a file from a branch? how can I do it?

Comment: @CarlosAndres use the ref parameter https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#parameters-1

Answer (score 10):

In case you want to download a zip file from `github` using `wget`

```
wget -O filename.zip https://github.com/downloads/user/repository/filename.zip?raw=true
```

see this [website](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/the-ultimate-wget-download-guide-with-15-awesome-examples/) for more details

Comment: You can download any file, not just .zip.

Answer (score 10):

1. On github, open the file you want to download
2. Locate the "Raw" button adjacent to the "Blame" button
3. Press "Alt" on your keyboard and left-click on your mouse at the same time
4. The file will download automatically in a ".txt" format (it did for me)
5. Change the ".txt" extension to ".csv" extension manually

This worked for me and I hope it does for you too.

Answer (score 10):

1. Copy page link simply
2. In command line type: `wget -L (exact copied link)`
3. Just replace `blob` to `raw` in **step 2**
4. Enter

Comment: I'm getting "zsh: command not found: wget"

Comment: @BrendanMetcalfe Is because you don't have package wget. Install first

Answer (score 8):

This method works for Windows as I have never used MAC so I don't know what are the alternate keys in MAC for the keys which I'm going to mention below.

Let's talk about the CSV files. IF you want to download the CSV file:

1. Go to that particular dataset that you want to download and click on it.
2. You will see "Raw" button on the top right side of the dataset.
3. Press "Alt" and then left click the "Raw" button.
4. The whole CSV will download in your system.

Remeber, you have to press Alt and left click simultaneously. Just clicking the "Raw" button will open up the CSV in the browser.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Best answer. Least number of steps. Nothing to install.

Answer (score 7):

You should just do it with the `raw` URL of your file.

For example to download the README of AFNetworking:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/master/README.md > ADREADME.md
```

As it is a public repo you don't need any credentials.
Please note the kind of url: `raw.githubusercontent.com/path/to/file`

Comment: This code doesn't seem to be R or terminal. Where would one use this code?

Comment: It's actually a terminal command based on `curl` and the output redirection with `>`

Answer (score 7):

#### GitHub Releases feature

Rather than link to download a specific file within the repo, you should use GitHub's **Releases** feature to associate downloadable data (such as compiled binaries) with the tagged version of the source code used to generate that data.

https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software

> We're excited to announce Releases, a workflow for shipping software to end users. Releases are first-class objects with changelogs and binary assets that present a full project history beyond Git artifacts.
>
> Releases are accompanied by release notes and links to download the software or source code.
>
> Following the conventions of many Git projects, releases are tied to Git tags. You can use an existing tag, or let releases create the tag when it's published.

[image]

Comment: Yes! This is the simplest solution, doable right from your browser! 1. From your repository main page, select `releases` 2. Click on the commit number. 3. Find the file you want, click on the three dots `...` and select `View file` 4. Click on `View raw` to download the file!!!

Answer (score 6):

Simply use wget with raw=True parameter

```
wget "https://github.com/user/repository/blob/master/directory/file_name?raw=True" -O target_path/file_name
```

Answer (score 4):

To download a file from a Github repo, use the 'curl' command with the link to the raw file.

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/filename --output filename
```

Add the --output option followed by the new filename to download the raw file to the newly created file.

Answer (score 3):

This would definitely work. At least in Chrome. Right click on the "Raw" icon -> *Save Link As*.

Comment: This saves the HTML file of the github page, which includes the github wrapper around the file.

Comment: @Gregor - FYI, It shouldn't, at least for pages that are TEXT.  If in doubt, LEFT-click on the "Raw" icon. This should open the text file in browser, WITHOUT any HTML. Now rt-click anywhere on page, and do "Save As...". (Or do Select-All / Copy, then Paste wherever you want)

Answer (score 2):

1. The page you linked to answers the first question.
2. GitHub also has a download facility for things like releases.
3. [Google Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Code) does not have [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) at all.
4. GitHub, Google Code and [SourceForge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SourceForge), just to start, are free hosting. SourceForge might still do [CVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System).

Answer (score 2):

On a Mac or Linux install [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) and use it to extract the file from Github like this:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: token <ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
   -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+raw" -L \
   https://api.github.com/repos/MY-ORG/MY-REPO/contents/MY-FILE-PATH | \
   jq -r '.content' | base64 --decode > MY_FILE_NAME.txt
```

[Documentation for the above command can be found here.](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents#get-repository-content)

Answer (score 1):

I think the new **`url`** structure is **`raw.giturl`** for example:

**[git file](https://github.com/EconometricsBySimulation/2013-05-29-ShinyApp/blob/master/Server.R)**

**[raw](https://raw.github.com/EconometricsBySimulation/2013-05-29-ShinyApp/master/Server.R)**

Comment: Sometimes the raw url is like this instead (raw.githubusercontent.com): https://raw.githubusercontent.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/master/dist/jquery.handsontable.full.js

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to use curl and firefox... you could use the [cliget](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cliget/) add-on which generates a curl call including all authentication mechanisms (aka cookies).

So right click on the `raw` button cliget->"copy url for link" and then paste that into a shell. You will get your file even if you had to log-in to see it.

Answer (score 1):

I recently found a service called `gitzip` and its also open source:

site - http://kinolien.github.io/gitzip/

repo - https://github.com/KinoLien/gitzip

Vist the above site, enter the repo or directory URL, you can download individual files or whole directory as a zip file.

Comment: But how do I only download `jszip.min.js` from that repository? *troll face*

Comment: open the file in github and then go to raw. You should see then the source code of the file and then you can download it useing the browser with right click mouse and save as. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Now it's possible to download any file or any particular folder within the repository using this google chrome extention:

**GitZip for github  :**
**link : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gitzip-for-github/ffabmkklhbepgcgfonabamgnfafbdlkn**

### Usage :

1. In any GitHub public repos page.
2. Just double click on the items you need.
3. Click download button at bottom-right.
4. See the progress dashboard and wait for browser trigger download.
5. Get the ZIP file.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to the script and click "Raw"

Then copy the link and download it with the aria2c link.

Eg: aria2c https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kodamail/gscript/master/color.gsf

Trick: the file I wanted to download is,
https://github.com/kodamail/gscript*/blob*/master/color.gsf

just modify the link into
https://**raw**.github**usercontent**.com/kodamail/gscript/master/color.gsf

Remove the italic texts and add bold texts in the same format, it will give you the right link.

which can be used with aria2c,wget or with curl, I used aria2c here.

Answer (score 1):

My simple way to do it is:

1. click the 'Raw' button to get the file contents of github_csv.csv shown on the browser.
2. Then create file.csv and open it in a text editor like notepad
3. Then copy the file content from the website and paste it on the file.csv
4. Your file.csv is  github_csv.csv

Answer (score 1):

I. If you wanner download a file like a .so other than source code, try click `Download` button as below:

[image]

The file will download tru your browser.

II. If u want to download source code, click `Raw` and will go to the raw.. page,
[image]

Simple copy/paste or use curl or wget command to get it in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

1. On the right hand side just below "Clone in Desktop" it say's "Download Zip file"
2. Download Zip File
3. Extract the file

Comment: Is there any way to do this in such a way that you have the lfs file contents?

Answer (score 0):

For users with GitHub Enterprise you need to construct URL in following scheme

`Invoke-WebRequest http://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/repos/my-org/my-repo/contents/myfiles/file.txt -Headers @{"Authorization"="token 8d795936d2c1b2806587719b9b6456bd16549ad8"}`

Details can be found here

http://artisticcheese.blogspot.com/2017/04/how-to-download-individual-files-from.html

Answer (score 0):

I used the following format, and I feel it's important to inform about the path.

```
https://github.com/user/repository/raw/branch/filename
```

^^^the above is not very complete in my mind

```
https://github.com/<user>/<repoROOTname>/blob/master/<path>/<filename>?raw=true
```

some said raw.github.com or raw instead of blob, but the 2nd line works for me and I hope will help others...

2¢

Answer (score 0):

You can try [github-files-fetcher](https://github.com/Gyumeijie/github-files-fetcher), it is a command line tool which downloads a single folder or file from a GitHub repo.

Think a real scenario: you were visiting the following webpage page and wanna download the `async` subdirectory alone.

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples

> sorry for not being allowed to post images.

With The `github-files-fetcher`, you should first copy the `url` of that page, which is https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/async, and then run the command below in command line:

`fetcher --url=https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/async`

Answer (score 0):

If you use **npm**, just run following command line and finally, it **won't** download any **npm** package except for this github file

```sh
npx config-pack https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/README.md
```

See [config-pack](https://github.com/zixiCat/config-pack) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Use the pattern `f'{host}/{user}/{repo}/{branch}/{file}'`. To have a concrete example, do in Python:

```
import pandas as pd
host = 'raw.github.com'
user = 'fivethirtyeight'
repo = 'data'
branch = 'master'
file = 'births/US_births_2000-2014_SSA.csv'
url = f'https://{host}/{user}/{repo}/{branch}/{file}'
df = pd.read_csv(url,sep=',',header=0)
df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer if you need to download a raw file and wget and curl are not working especially if you are working on a linux terminal:

git clone the whole repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/sample-repo
```

change directory to the cloned repo

```
cd sample-repo
```

move the raw file to the desired directory (many times this could be the parent of sample repo and change directory

```
mv raw path/to/desired/dir && cd path/to/desired/dir

OR

mv raw .. && cd ..
```

Remove the github repo using 'force'

```
rm -rf sample-repo
```

Answer (score 0):

### New Github Code Search

The new code preview feature on github allows to download a file directly without any extension or workaround.
**Note**: This feature still in beta so beta access is required.

Enroll in beta features:

- **Enroll yourself in [beta list wishlist](https://github.com/features/code-search-code-view/signup) to use the new code search navigation**
- Once it's enabled then open the file and click on download raw file

  [image: demo]

Info: Previously, it was under beta features but now it has been moved to separate beta Wishlist.

Alternately, Use online search portal

1. Visit Github search with search as code and auto_entroll: https://github.com/search?type=code&auto_enroll=true
2. Search your repo (e.g. user:pavneet-sing room repo) and open file
3. **Click on download raw file**

[image]]