# github picture path

Tags: github

## pictures can't show in github

I use markdown to write note, and when I want to add a picture, I do this:

`![Alt desc](/home/user_name/repo_name/pic/pic_name "desc")`

here comes a problem, when I `git push` the repo, the github coouldn't recognize the

absolute path in my computer

so my **question** is that what the picture path is in github and markdown file?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You're expected to use an absolute path to a http accessible image

- `![Alt desc](http://www.example.com/image.png)`

If you're willing to link against your own repository, you should use the **[`raw` url format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4605068/335418)**.

For instance, the following markdown

- `![logo](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/raw/master/square-logo.png)`

should display the following image

[image: logo]

**Note:** An alternate raw format is also supported. The image above can also be accessed through the following url: https://raw.github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/master/square-logo.png

## Update

Following your comment.

The following markdown in [basic_option.md](https://github.com/liangxiao3/redhat_note/blob/master/basic_option.md) won't work.

- `> ![Alt vmware](https://github.com/liangxiao3/redhat_note/blob/master/pic/basic_vmware.jpg "vmware tool")`

Switching it to the markdown below should fix this
Indeed, you didn't use the **raw url format** (see above)

- `![Alt vmware](https://github.com/liangxiao3/redhat_note/raw/master/pic/basic_vmware.jpg)`

Comment: what is the format of this path? In my github repository, my pictures are in pic directory, how could  I refer to  it ?

Comment: Could you share your github repository http url and point at the failing link?

Comment: here comes my github redhat_note repository ,   

`git://github.com/liangxiao3/redhat_note.git`,


and  u can check `basic_option.md`, there is a picture which can't display regularly

Comment: Thanks! It's weird though because sometimes it is `/raw/master/` and sometimes `/raw/main/`... I always struggled with that :-)

Answer (score 9):

You can just use relative path, like `![](pic/pic_name.png)`.

Comment: relative path is **not** uselful

Comment: when I click the fragment of picture, it could turn to the right place of the picture in github, but It can not display in the current page