# How to download file in git repo using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, git, github

I want to download a file in git repo without clone it.
For example `lodash` git repo :

https://github.com/lodash/lodash/

in that git there is file `lodash.js`:

https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/lodash.js

I have try using `nodegit` but still need to clone all files first.

How to download `lodash.js` file only in git repo using nodejs?

Comment: Can't you just use the github raw url !? E.g. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lodash/lodash/master/lodash.js

Answer (score 2):

It is easy enough to curl a [single file from a git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4605068/6309)

```
curl -L -O github.com/user/repository/raw/branch/filename
```

Since you have nodejs, you can use [`chriso/curlrequest`](https://github.com/chriso/curlrequest), a node wrapper for `curl`.

```
npm install curlrequest
raw.githubusercontent.com/lodash/lodash/master/lodash.js 
curl.request({ url: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lodash/lodash/master/lodash.js' }, function (err, stdout, meta) {
    console.log('%s %s', meta.cmd, meta.args.join(' '));
});
```

Comment: i dont know why, but curlrequest getting error when download, may be there is other way?

Answer (score 2):

You could use download the zip using the direct URL (https://github.com/lodash/lodash/archive/master.zip) and use adm-zip (https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip) to unzip it locally.