# how to download single folder OR file in gitlab repository

Tags: git, copy, repository, clone, gitlab

i have one repository. In this repository multiple folders are available.

i have required only one folder in this repository.

i am already try to following command but it's not working.

git clone

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to clone a git repository's sub-directory only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only)

Comment: Forum topic: https://forum.gitlab.com/t/how-to-checkout-or-clone-sub-directory-from-gitlab-project/2506

Seems like there isn't a way to do it from the Gitlab GUI - seems to be a bit more support in Github http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604663/download-single-files-from-github

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Is there any way to clone a git repository's sub-directory only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only)

> Use a [sparse checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13738951/278405), available since version 1.7.0.

Comment: Beware that it downloads all repository history content also.

Answer (score 8):

If only the content of that folder is of interest (not its history), you can, since GitLab 1.11 (May 2019) download only a folder.

> ### Download archives of directories within a repository

[image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/11_11/repo_download-archive.png]

> Depending on the type of project and its size, downloading an archive of the entire project may be slow or unhelpful – particularly in the case of large monorepos.
>
> **In GitLab 11.11, you can now download an archive of the contents of the current directory, including subdirectories, so that you download only the files you need**.

From [issue 24704](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/24704): see [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/#download-source-code).

---

With **GitLab 14.4** (Oct. 2021), you have:

- [issue 28827](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/28827) "**Download a (sub-)folder from a repository via the Repositories API**",
- resolved with [MR 71431](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/71431) and [commit 1b4e0a1](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/commit/1b4e0a1e2460baef90d5af689a21a0b6c46efd14):

```sh
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" \
"https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/repository/archive?sha=<commit_sha>&path=<path>"
```

It was not somehow mentioned in the "[GitLab 1.44 released](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/10/22/gitlab-14-4-released/)" page though.

Comment: Can we download using curl or wget?

Comment: @Ashwani Not yet: that is followed by https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/28827

Answer (score 7):

From Gitlab 14.4 download folder is supported natively. See the [doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#get-file-archive)

Example:

```sh
https://<GITLAB-URL>/api/v4/projects/<project-id>/repository/archive?path=<subfolder-path>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a (far from perfect) piece of `sh` code to fetch a file or whole directory from repo using GiLab'a API I wrote. Enjoy if you find it useful :)

```
#!/bin/sh

GITLAB_API_URL=https://gitlab.com/api/v4
GITLAB_TOKEN=<YOUR TOKEN>
PROJECT=path/to/gitlab/project

PROJECT_ENC=$(echo -n ${PROJECT} | jq -sRr @uri)

function fetchFile() {
  FILE=$1
  FILE_ENC=$(echo -n ${FILE} | jq -sRr @uri)

  curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_TOKEN}" "${GITLAB_API_URL}/projects/${PROJECT_ENC}/repository/files/${FILE_ENC}?ref=master" -o /tmp/file.info
  if [ "$(dirname $FILE)" != "." ]; then
    mkdir -p $(dirname $FILE)
  fi
  cat /tmp/file.info | jq -r '.content' | tr -d "\n" | jq -sRr '@base64d' > $FILE
  rm /tmp/file.info
}

function fetchDir() {
  DIR=$1
  FILES=$(curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${GITLAB_TOKEN}" "${GITLAB_API_URL}/projects/${PROJECT_ENC}/repository/tree?ref=master&per_page=100&recursive=true&path=${DIR}" | jq -r '.[] | select(.type == "blob") | .path')
  for FILE in $FILES; do
    fetchFile $FILE
  done
}

fetchDir <REPO_DIR_TO_FETCH>
```

It uses curl and [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) (version at least 1.6).

**Be careful if you may have more then 100 files in a directory** since the above `fetchDir` function gets only 100 files. To make it work always you should add some loop there.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Lzydorr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/881107/izydorr). I needed this in Powershell to get version in maven project. This function download pom.xml and find "version" tag. I post it here, in case any other needs this in PS.

This function can for example be called like this:

```
$version = gitlabFetchVersion "integration/$appname" "master"
```

```sh
function gitlabFetchVersion {
  Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
  #$project = "integration/ssys-integration"
  $project = $($args[0])
  $project_enc = [System.Web.HTTPUtility]::UrlEncode($project)
  $file="pom.xml"
  $branch=$($args[1])
  $GITLAB_API_URL="https://git.infosynergi.no/api/v4"
  $GITLAB_TOKEN="XXXXXXX"
  $file_enc=[System.Web.HTTPUtility]::UrlEncode($file)
  $headers = @{
    Authorization = $GITLAB_TOKEN
    Accept        = "application/json"
  }

  $url = $GITLAB_API_URL + "/projects/" + $project_enc + "/repository/files/" + $file_enc + "?ref="+$branch
  $pom64 = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers @{ 'PRIVATE-TOKEN'='qPxLx5Hk5cB4HLgbVDsQ' } -Uri $url
  $xml = [xml]([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($pom64.content)))
  $pversion = $xml.project.version
  Write-Host "Version: " $pversion   
  return $pversion
}
```