# How to fetch content of single file from private git repo with php

Tags: php, github-api

I am trying to fetch content of single file from GitHub with php . I have searched a lot but no luck . Here are some links [Github access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604663/download-single-files-from-github)

all these are working for public repo . i also have tried it with access token

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/builderux/dev_elead/master/Elead.php?access_token=**************************************
```

this token is working to download zip file . But for single file it is showing not found error

Comment: ...why don't you use `git` for it?

Comment: I am working on WordPress plugin updater so i need to do it programmatically

Comment: Accessing git from wordpress.... please don't

Comment: can you please explain why ? But it is the requirment

Answer (score 0):

You can use GitHub's [Contents API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents) to obtain the Base64-encoded contents of a file (for files of up to one megabyte) by issuing an HTTP GET request to `/repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path`.

PHP's `base64_decode()` function should then be able to decode this back to the original file contents.