# Is there a standard way to specify a file within a git uri?

Tags: git, uri

For example, say I want to link directly to `/README.rst` in the `master` branch on `git://git@github.com:drathier/stack-overflow-import.git`. Is there a standard way to format this in a uri? We're already using the path field to specify what repo we're talking about on this domain.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://github.com/drathier/stack-overflow-import/blob/4c34886ecfbaa12426a9d3e09f9d1f80888652b2/README.rst
```

Is this what you're looking for ? Tip from [here](https://help.github.com/articles/getting-permanent-links-to-files/)

Or maybe interested in the raw file content:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drathier/stack-overflow-import/4c34886ecfbaa12426a9d3e09f9d1f80888652b2/README.rst
```

As for a *git* url:

> [Git does not support downloading parts of the repository.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4605068/281545)

See linked answer for using  Wget or cURL with the http urls linked to above