# git pull and push specific files without the repository saved locally

Tags: git, github

I have a couple questions but I'll put them together given they look quite similar.

Let's say I have a repository called Repo, and it contains two folders, A and B.

Via terminal (and given I don't have the project in my machine), how can I...

(1) ...clone only folder A from Repo to my machine?

(2) ...send a file/folder C to Repo?

Comment: cloning subdirectory is not possible in git itself. You might try using github API, with for example `curl` utility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that repo is on GitHub (since there is a github tag), you can:

- get just one file with the raw api (see "[Download single files from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18155172/6309)")

  ```
  https://raw.github.com/<username>/<repo>/<branch>/some_directory/file.rb
  ```

That works well for files, and you can repeat that for each file in order to download a folder.
But if said folder content is large, you are best to use the zip link associated to each repo: that won't download the all history, only the current repo state, which is smaller. From that archive, you can extract your folder. See "[Download a single folder or directory from a GitHub repo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7106012/6309)" (maybe you can avoid that with [an SVN syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32545187/6309))

For uploading anything to GitHub, you need to be the owner of the destination repo: you might have to fork the target repo in order to get your own: See [GitHub  fork repo](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/).

From there you can [directly edit a file](https://help.github.com/articles/editing-files-in-your-repository/). This would be cumbersome for a all folder though.

Answer (score -1):

#### To clone

If you are using git bash
`git clone [url]`

Example:
`https://github.com/mycode`

#### To commit and push

1. `git init`
2. `git add [filename]`
3. `git commit -m "First commit"`
4. `git remote add origin remote repository URL`
5. `git push origin master`

(This creates a local clone which you can delete later)

### Reference

1. [How to add an existing project](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/)
2. [How to clone repository](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository)

Comment: if I understood, with this you are able to send a file to the project without having to download the whole repository?

Comment: @DcCoO Suppose you are working on a file. Then you want to add it to repo, Then you follow what I did in second case.

Comment: @DcCoO You said A or B is not in your machine. So you clone it. And in the second case the file is assumed to be in machine.

Comment: Not really.. in both cases, I don't have the repository locally. In the first case I want to get a specific file (e.g. A) from Repo without downloading Repo completely. In the second case I want to send a file to Repo without downloading it as well.

Comment: @DcCoO.: I am afraid that there is no proper way to do that.

Comment: @VonC.: So my answer is also right...look it is not possible to do it epo to repo? right?