# How do I extract a jar file from github?

Tags: github, jar, export

I would like to extract the jar file from this GitHub project.

https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=3761

How does one extract it?

Comment: Jars are zip as long as I know. Just unzip them.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will want to download the file from github

Then, if you have the [Java Developer Kit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) all you need to do is simply run this command in command prompt or terminal

```
jar xf jar-file [archived-file(s)]
```

For example

```
jar xf TicTacToe.jar TicTacToe.class images/cross.gif
```

All the commands above come directly from [this article](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/unpack.html) provided by Oracle

Answer (score 0):

IF by "extract" you mean "get only one file from a GitHub repo", like [`gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar`](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer/blob/master/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar), you can use its [raw address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4605068/6309)

```
https://github.com/username/repository/raw/$changeset_hash/path/to/file
```

But if you mean: the jar resulting from the compilation of the all GitHub project, then you would need to clone and build it first, since the [AndroidPdfViewer/releases](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer/releases) do not include the final jar.