# curl command to download a original file from organisation's git repo using curl

Tags: curl, github

I am trying to download a file from git reposiroty by using "curl -u : -o  -O -L "
But it is downloading the html file and not the exact .py file which i mentioned in curl command.

Kindly help with this

Comment: Which is the url you append after the curl command?

Comment: curl -u username:Private access token -o filename -O -L "Whole file link of repo"

Comment: I provide you an answer, let me know if it works

Comment: since it's organization's repo, how to replace "raw.githubusercontent.com"                       eg: path to my file will look like below "https://repository.orggoc.com/file path"

Comment: "raw.githubusercontent.com" is a fixed part, to open a file in "raw" version

Comment: kindly say how to fill user and repository fileds with

Comment: You can't modify it, you need this "raw.githubusercontent.com". Here's an example from Nodejs repository [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodejs/node/master/configure.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodejs/node/master/configure.py)

Comment: where do i mention my reposiory name in above link.since my repository address itself is "/repository.<organization>goc.com/"

Comment: and when i navigate to the raw link of that specific file..link looks like "https://repository.<organizationgoc>.com/cri/CRI_Platform/raw/master/<file_path>/<file_name>.py"

Comment: Try using this link you find navigating to the raw version

Comment: that link itself is the raw file link of my repo...thats why i am confused to give "raw.githubusercontent.com"

Comment: Because I'am using github and it works with "raw.githubusercontent.com", try using your link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download single files from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604663/download-single-files-from-github)

Comment: i believe raw file path for normal git users looks like link sent by you.in my case raw file link is different... it wont start "raw.githubusercontent.com" is what i am trying to say

Answer (score 1):

You have to reference to the "raw" version of the file:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repository/branch/filename
```