# Config Server in Play framework 2.7

Tags: scala, playframework, configserver

I am implementing a web socket server application using play framework 2.7
I would like to implement a remote configuration where all the application's 
configuration should reside in a github.

When i searched for documents to implement it, i found below url,

```
https://github.com/play-rconf
```

but accessing configuration from github is not listed.
Is there any better way or document do access the config server from github (like in Spring) ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [play-rconf-http](https://github.com/play-rconf/play-rconf-http) by specifying a URL of your config file:

```
remote-configuration {

  ## Provider - HTTP
  # ~~~~~
  # Retrieves configuration from a simple HTTP server
  http {

    # URL where is located the configuration file to fetch. You can
    # use basic authentication
    url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<user>/<repo>/<branch>/<path-to-file>"
    url = ${?REMOTECONF_HTTP_URL}
  }
}
```

You can use basic authentication as well.
Look [Download single files from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604663/download-single-files-from-github) for more info regarding GitHub link.