# How to fetch or view file.txt (content) using gh or git cl. (GitHub)

Tags: git, github

i am trying to view file.txt from repo via gh or git cli cmds. Help me. File is at xyz/file.txt.
xyz is the repo name.

I tried `gh repo view` & `git show`
But nothing works.

(I need to view without cloning.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4604663/7976758