Download dataset from Github
I want to download the dirty_data.xlsx dataset from Github... I thought I can do that after watch several tutorial, and even the other similar questions in stackoverflow... but still fail.
Can anyone help on it?
The below is the attempt I have tried :
url <- "https://github.com//sfirke//janitor//blob//main//dirty_data.xlsx"

download.file(url,
              destfile = basename(url),
              mode = "wb")

data <- readxl::read_xlsx(basename(url))

But I got the error below :
Error in utils::unzip(zip_path, list = TRUE) : 
  zip file 'C:\Learnings\dirty_data.xlsx' cannot be opened


You're using the wrong link - that's the link to the page it's hosted on, not to the file.  Use https://github.com/sfirke/janitor/raw/main/dirty_data.xlsx.

@lotus thank you! But I am wondering, how do you manage to get this link?
Because I can't see the "raw" path from https://github.com/sfirke/janitor/ ...

You can find the link to the raw data on the page you were trying to use.  Also, this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604663/download-single-files-from-github

@lotus thank you! Very helpful of you. Thank you very much and very appreciate it.

You can read the dataset directly from Github after using the raw link as suggested by @lotus.
rio::import("https://github.com/sfirke/janitor/raw/main/dirty_data.xlsx",skip = 1)

